# Data created in Dockerfile does not exist within container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I appreciate your help!

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:slim

RUN mkdir -p /project
WORKDIR /project

# workdir is empty
RUN ls -a
COPY . /project

# workdir is full
RUN ls -a

# this command create node_modules folder on it own
RUN npm install

# I have node_modules folder with packages
RUN ls -a
RUN ls -d node_modules/*
```

Last outputs are:

```
Step 8/9 : RUN ls -a
 ---> Running in 90d8793f491a
.
..
.babelrc
.editorconfig
.eslintignore
.eslintrc.js
.git
.gitignore
.postcssrc.js
Dockerfile-dev
README.md
build
config
docker-compose.dev.yml
index.html
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
src
static
test
Removing intermediate container 90d8793f491a
 ---> b563d272b270
Step 9/9 : RUN ls -d node_modules/*
 ---> Running in a14bb4024e5e
node_modules/@babel
node_modules/@types
node_modules/abab
node_modules/abbrev
node_modules/accepts
node_modules/acorn
```

But when I look at the container's files from the following command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml run project ls
```

I have no **node_modules** folder (folder with dependencies) and my container cannot start because of it:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml up

sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! project@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-04-11T19_09_35_669Z-debug.log
```

The **docker-compose** is simple:

```
version: '3'
services:
  project:
    container_name: project
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - .:/project
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

The questions are: why it happens? How to solve the problem?

Comment: You're mounting something to `/project`, thus masking content previously defined there in the Dockerfile.

Comment: In dockerfile replace line COPY . /project with COPY . .

Comment: @JinnaBalu, it is the same command as mine, because there is no difference between dot (project dir) and /project (because it is same project dir, slash allows to access it from root). I did what you said anyway to approve my point and I was right.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, I tried to remove volumes from compose (no mounting), but it did not help. Or what did I do wrong?

Comment: Unrelated comment on your Dockerfile: you should remove `RUN mkdir -p /project` because the `WORKDIR /project` directive already performs that.

Comment: @ErikMD, yes, you are right! Thanks you! But this fix did not help me with my problem (I have totally the same situation even I fix excess mkdir).

Comment: First, can you try running the image directly, without relying on docker-compose? i.e., run in the Dockerfile folder, `docker build -f Dockerfile-dev -t image-name .` then something like `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 image-name npm run dev` ?

Comment: @ErikMD, yeah! It works properly! What is problem in compose? Thanks you!

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd say either your .yml file is incomplete, or the change you performed (removing the `volume:` field) did not triggered the creation of another container...

Comment: Suggestion: firstly, do `docker ps -a` (resp. `docker images`) to find the old version of the container (resp. image) and delete it using something like `docker rm project` (resp. `docker rmi the-name-of-the-image`)

Comment: @ErikMD, I am always clean all images and containers before each attempt of a build.

Comment: OK. lastly, [even if it is not mandatory](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#build), try to add an `image: image-name` field in your .yml file (below the `project:` node) to specify the name of the built image (also to avoid any confusion, maybe you could choose 3 different names: for the service (project), for the image name (e.g., project-image) and for the `container_name` (e.g., project-app)), then remove the `volume:` node and try again...

Comment: @ErikMD, weird situation. I have deleted volumes and it works good now (with my initial setup). But I cannot delete it totally, because I need to change data on the local host and get the same changes within container.

Comment: @ErikMD, it is like volumes (if specified) temporary override container data (container data in this case == local host), but if there are no volumes container data == container data created during Dockerfile.

Comment: OK; BTW about volumes have you taken a look at [dev-best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/dev-best-practices/#where-and-how-to-persist-application-data) ? because I recall that the `volumes:` instruction that you had used is *not a volume* but a *bind mount*, that bind mounts are especially useful for the dev phase only, and finally as pointed out by @OliverCharlesworth if you use a bind mount, you should be careful with the path chosen inside the container (to avoid overwriting the existing files over there).

Comment: I recommend creating an src folder inside your package to keep your source files and bind mounting that folder in your docker-compose file for development purposes. Also unrelated but good practice, is to copy your package.json and run 'npm i' before copying your src files in the Dockerfile. This prevents pulling all your dependencies every time you build if you haven't changed your package.json.

Answer (score -4):

*why it happens?*
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4361#issuecomment-167156818

*How to solve the problem?*
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4361#issuecomment-210231967

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/165483) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)